How can I get an RTH moving average onto an ETH session chart?
I cannot get an RTH moving average to show properly on an ETH session chart. It shows up as the ETH moving average.
//RTH SMA Inputs
rthTF = input.timeframe("", "RTH SMA Timeframe", group="RTH SMAS")
displayRTHSMA200 = input.bool(true, title="Display RTHSMA200", group="RTH SMAS")

//Plot SMAs for RTH
rthSMA200 = request.security(ticker.modify(syminfo.tickerid, session.regular), rthTF, ta.sma(close, 200), barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(displayRTHSMA200 ? rthSMA200:na, "rthSMA200", color.aqua, linewidth = 2)

I expected it to draw the 200MA for the RTH on the ETH session chart. All it did was overlap the 200MA for the ETH session.
I am able to show an ETH moving average on the RTH session chart.
I thought this might be simple enough to do but I can't seem to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Allow me to add:
This works on stocks just fine. My issue with it is that it doesn't work on futures.
